# Check if any of values exists in array

Tags: php, arrays

Want to shorten this code

```
if( (in_array('2', $values)) or (in_array('5', $values)) or (in_array('6', $values)) or (in_array('8', $values)) ){
echo 'contains 2 or 5 or 6 or 8';
}
```

Tried this

```
(in_array(array('2', '5', '6', '8'), $values, true))
```

but as i understand true is only if all the values exists in array

Please, advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-intersect.php), eg

```
if (count(array_intersect($values, array('2', '5', '6', '8'))) > 0) {
    echo 'contains 2 or 5 or 6 or 8';
}
```

Example here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/GFiLGx

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function like this :

```
function array_in_array($array_values, $array_check) {
  foreach($array_values as $value)
    if (in_array($value, $array_check))
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even omit **count** to shorten your code.

```
$input = array(2,3);
if (array_intersect($input, $values)) {
    echo 'contains 2 or 3';    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$targets = array(2,5,6,8);
$isect = array_intersect($targets, $values);
if (count($isect) != 0) {
// do stuff
}
```